# Strange typescript extends behaviour

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a flexible class where some return types are depended of what you give as generic. This class should act like a configuration class for a path selector. So I developed an abstracted class that has two generics. `T` extends an object and `X` is `keyof T`. Where `X` gives you to possibility to say this is your identification property.

The problem started when I added a property that can hold a path. So I gave it the type `Record<T[X], T[X]|null`. T[X] should always be a string or a number. But typescript was not happy with this Record type and gave me the following error:

```
Type 'T[X]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.(2344)
```

So after some playing and debugging we made a mapping type that changes all the properties if they are not string or number to never. This should fix the issue that it was possible to set identifitication type (`T[X]`) to something else than string or a number.

But then we found this weird behaviour of Typescript. We have two different types (`T`) that have both one property named `id` with type number. I was expecting that the following conditional type should give type true. But it gave a different result:

code:

```
type Test = T['id'] extends number ? true : false
// This should not give an error becease Test should extend true and not false.
const test: Test = true
ˆˆˆ Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
```

Can someone give me a solution to this error and also explain why this behaviour is?

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewFYQMbCgXigbwFBSFQCWAJgPwBcUAdgK4C2ARhHAUQpDdUwggDYQAhjTwBfPHlCQoAZWBw66OnAgB9GglLRs+IiVLV6zVu0KcI3KLwHDREqeGjy4xGgHMAzgEEapAHKMLHCeADwAKgB8WLjsANowJDRQANYQIAgAZlDhUEKeOQkAulAQAB7AlqQF8BZwoADS6VDksFBGEABurEXUdDQpmgDu9pIA9GN5TJ4KQuhQqPz5BQAiIDRCDMSoshCC6ABCCGURpRVVBQhMKOgANFAAGmeVfgVpGdkubl6+AUGsYSi0XwQmms3mi2WUDWGy2Oz2aGARxOuXKL2qUCuN2A9yeaIuqXSWRywLMUDAQmAAAtqAAlNAIOCkCJxB5Fe7hVlFAA+9H4-GiugkDkhnhqiGxu32wEZp3xrzkCiUwBU6k02m5tWxUAAZLgyNR-AgaIF+aDBKEtYi4gByMg2oqRMTReUYmGbbZSxHIiL3O2kG2ksmoY0zRToRkACgAlLF9PpPHRIHAY2T9NTiJ4AHSqPysGCUqmptNEaTQcIQGYxTn+h3PAnGYItKBK6DUTJCfieCAlwgTHJUzNQTxUhB0fikWgIDDuYjdPLJViIODWNDCbs5SsYEdjif1vwtxTQESTzQYDtdiBZ3sLUMYSozagVqvYVtkhz6XPaOAF6kxuPxoQGbZhS1IxHogHxgAjNQAAstw3vosHUAATAADAhkHxuhRjjvwN4SPowpQHgQA)

Comment: Your playground link is corrupt and there is no [mre] in the text of the question.  Please make sure to include any example code as plain text in the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your error and the link doesn't link to the code.

This works just as expected and does not yield an error.

```
type T = { 'id': number }

type Test = T['id'] extends number ? true : false

const test: Test = true
```

It's not necessary always "intuitive" when this evaluates to true or false, depending on the actual type of T and id, but I've found no strangeness in this definition. I would suspect that one of two things is going on. You've got a weird compiler / linter or there is something else going, maybe aliasing, hard to tell without the code.

EDIT (after code):
I see. I believe the problem is that since we're in a class, `T` is fixed at type definition of `Test`, and `T['id']` is a member of a union (but not the union itself) depending on the fixed `T`. But that means that TS can not determine what the type `Test` actually is. It's not the union `true | false`. It's only `true` or only `false` in respect to the actual `T`. In other words, you can never assign a value to `Test<T>` without determining the kind of `T['id']` first at runtime and telling TS what that type is.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the link and my implementation is different than yours. Please check my new playground. But thank you in advanced for helping me.

Comment: I've updated the response with what I believe to be the issue. Basically you're forcing TS into a branching issue, the type Test is one of two types (not a union) at which point you can never assign a value to test since TS has no way to know which of the two options T satisfies (and T is already fixed, (inside constructor)).